# Very strange behavior with array declaration

Tags: c, arrays

I have a simple function:

```
    DoRead(double *writeArray){
//GblOutData is an array of length 80, where each element is 1
    writeArray=GblOutData;
//prints out 1
    printf("%f",writeArray[5]);
    return 0;
    }
```

what happens when I call DoRead():

```
double data[80];    
DoRead(data);
printf("%f",data[5]);
//prints out 0.000000 instead of 1
```

I can't figure out why this is happening. Any ideas?

Comment: Because you're never setting `data[5]` to 1? FYI, you're not changing the parameter outside the function when you do `writeArray=GblOutData;`, you're just changing the pointer inside the function and actually just printing `GblOutData[5]`.

Comment: @SethCarnegie you're right! worked when I just manually set writeArray[5]=1

Answer (score 6):

All that the line

```
writeArray=GblOutData;
```

does is change the meaning of the variable writeArray inside the function DoRead(). When it returns, the outer variable data has not changed. You want to copy the contents, possibly with memcpy:

```
memcpy(writeArray, writeArray=GblOutData, 80*sizeof *writeArray);
```

Comment: Of course, you need to always make sure the two arrays are the same size. When this program grows up, it is going to be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the address to data. One solution can be (but personally I wouldn't do something like this):

```
DoRead(double **writeArray){
 *writeArray=GblOutData;
  ....
}

DoRead((double**) &data);
```

Comment: unfortunately I'm not free to change how the params are set/called in DoRead, I can do whatever I want inside the function however.

Comment: *Probably not* what he wanted to do in this case as he already allocated an array outside.

Comment: I would go for drdwilcox solution, with memcpy. Anyway, I've only tried to demonstrate what was happening.